# One .po file for each .py script

Tags: python-3.x, gettext

In my package, I would like to use one .po file for each .py script it contains.
Here is my file tree :

```
foo
   mainscript.py
   commands/
      commandOne.py
   locales/fr/LC_MESSAGES/
      mainscript_fr.po
      commandOne_fr.po
```

In the mainscript.py, I got the following line to apply gettext to the strings :

```
if "fr" in os.environ['LANG']:
    traduction = gettext.translation('mainscript_fr', localedir='./locales', languages=['fr'])
    traduction.install()
else:
    gettext.install('')
```

Until now, it is working as expected. But now I would like to add another .po file to translates the strings in commandOne.py.
I tried the following code :

```
if "fr" in os.environ['LANG']:
    traduction = gettext.translation('commandOne_fr', localedir='../locales', languages=['fr'])
    traduction.install()
else:
    gettext.install('')
```

But I get a "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'commandOne_fr' "

How can I use multiple file like that ? The package being a cli, there is many strings in a single file because of the help man and verbose mode...etc and this is not acceptable to have a single .po file with hundreds of strings.

Note : The mainscript.py calls a function from commandOne.py, which is itself inherited from an abstract class that contains other strings to translate... so I hope if any solution exists that it will also be applicable to the abstract class file.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Translations are retrieved from `.mo` files, not `.po` files, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.translation. Most probably you have to compile `CommandOne_fr.po` with the program `msgfmt` into `CommandOne_fr.mo`.

Two more hints:

What you are doing looks like a premature optimization. You won't have any performance problem until the number of translations gets really big. Rather wait for that to happen.

Why the `_fr` in the name of the translation files? The language code `fr` is already a path component.

Comment: Yup, the .mo files are also in the locales folder with their .po files. I didnt want to put too much unuseful informations in my tree.
The thing is I will not be the only one working on this, in a few month it will be maintained by others and I want them to not be lost if they need to correct something in a particular string.
The "_fr" is in case the file gets lost out of its locales folder, but I admit this is a little bit too much x)

Comment: But you just made me think : maybe we can compile multiples .po files into 1 .mo file, then the problem would be solved

Comment: You can merge multiple po files into one po file because xgettext will accept po files as input without any further options. That merged po file can then be compiled into one mo file. But I still don't see the point.

Comment: From a translator's perspective it would usually be impractical and inconvenient to have multiple small `.po` files to translate, instead of one larger file.

Comment: @LauriNurmi, see my previous commennt. You can easily merge and later split `.po` files.